# Game Center specific matchmaking

Tags: objective-c, game-center, multiplayer

I'm developing a multiplayer game via Game Center.

So I have players with different groups (some sort of clans). All matches requires exactly 2 players. How can I do matchmaking only for players with different groups?

E.g.:

`Clan 1 + Clan 2 = true;`

`Clan 5 + Clan 5 = false;`

`Clan 5 + Clan 6 = true;`

I know there is a `playerGroup` property, but it performs exactly the opposite thing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `playerAttributes` property of the match request should be able to do what you want. It's a 32-bit mask that, when set to a non-zero value, players will only automatch into the game if they complete the mask (OR'd together) to 0xFFFFFFFF. See [an example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW12) here.

However, the problem is you indicate you have many more clans than players. If you have 6 and define them as:

```
#define CLAN1 0xFF00000F
#define CLAN2 0xFF0000F0
#define CLAN3 0xFF000F00
#define CLAN4 0xFF00F000
#define CLAN5 0xFF0F0000
#define CLAN6 0xFFF00000
```

Then the OR'd combination of just two players would never fully reach 0xFFFFFFFF. I think you can do what you want by inverting the masks, though, and using 0's instead of 1's to define the role you want.

```
#define CLAN1 0xFFFFFFF0
#define CLAN2 0xFFFFFF0F
#define CLAN3 0xFFFFF0FF
#define CLAN4 0xFFFF0FFF
#define CLAN5 0xFFF0FFFF
#define CLAN6 0xFF0FFFFF
```

Any two of those from different clans OR together as 0xFFFFFFFF. So, game center willing (which is always an iffy proposition), any two players from different clans should match; however, two players from the same clan should not.

Note: I'm probably stating the obvious here, but note that you could have up to 32 different clans if you define them in binary rather than hex, and thus use a single bit for each clan. I only used hex numbers here for readability.

Comment: You option is correct, but somehow Game Center doesn't start match within such players' attributes

Comment: Are you making a real time match or a turn-based match?

Comment: This is a real-time match. And I found out this:
`FFFF0000 | 0000FFFF = works fine`
`FFF00000 | 000FFFFF = works fine`
`FFF00000 | 00FFFFFF = doesn't work`
`WHATEVER | FFFFFFFF = works fine`

Comment: Wow, crazy. I think you should open a bug with apple on that.